# Mismatch on SQL_variant and DT_WSTR in BIDS Manager

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, bids, sql-variant

I'm using BIDS to update some data to SQL Server 2008 R2.

My source is a `varchar` and destination table has this column `VariantValue` as a `sql_variant` datatype. So I have used a derived column transformation to create a unicode new column with this expression: `(DT_WSTR,4000)(PNumber)`. Which means i'm converting a `varchar` into a `unicode` and inserting it into a `sql_variant` column

My slowly changing dimension connection manager is throwing this error:

> Cannot map columns of different types.
>   Column 'PNumber' is of type 'System.String' and column `VariantValue` is of type 'System.Object'

Comment: Because you cannot convert an object to nvarchar. sql_Variant datatype contains serveral datatypes ex int,binary or char values. And SSIS does not fully support sql_Variant and i can see you use 2008R2. Im not sure they even support it at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many restrictions for the Sql_Variant data types:

- varchar(max)
- varbinary(max)
- nvarchar(max)
- xml
- text
- ntext
- image
- rowversion (timestamp)
- sql_variant
- geography
- hierarchyid
- geometry
- User-defined types
- datetimeoffset

So i think that your row source is `Varchar(Max)` so even if you convert it to

```
(DT_STR,4000,1252)(PNumber)
```

It will work.

Or you can use a SQL command as Source and CAST the column to `VARCHAR(4000)` or `NVARCHAR(4000)` from it.

*Note: that when using `MAX` length, SSIS consider it as a blob data `DT_TEXT`*

**References**

- [sql_variant (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/sql-variant-transact-sql#restrictions)